# Iterate JSON array in angular controller

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to iterate through the array in Json and display the values in front end. I have given my code but I could not figure out where exactly I am wrong. I am not able to retrieve the values(startDate, endDate) inside the array and show them at front end.

`JSON`

```
"reportTypeObligationTypes": [{
    "reportTypeId": null,
        "consolidationScopeId": 4009,
        "startDate": "2014-01-01",
        "endDate": "9999-12-31",
        "frequencyCode": "Q",
        "reportTypeLabel": null,
        "reportTypeCode": null,
        "consolidationScopeCode": "C",
        "frequencyLabel": "Quarterly"
}]
```

Angular controller

```
xxxApp.controller('reportListController', function ($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {


    var service_url = "/mdmservice/services/reportTypeEntities/" + $routeParams.id;
    $http.get(service_url).success(

    function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.reportTypeEntities = data;
        angular.forEach($scope.reportTypeEntities, function (item) {
            console.log(item.reportTypeObligationTypes);
        })
    });

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 1000],
        paginationPageSize: 25,
    };
    $scope.gridOptions.data = 'reportTypeEntities';
    $scope.gridOptions.enableFiltering = true;
    $scope.gridOptions.enableGridMenu = true;
    $scope.gridOptions.fastWatch = true;

    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [{
        name: "entityName",
        width: "35%",
        cellTemplate: '<div style="margin-left: 5px;">' + '  <a href="#edit/{{row.entity.entityId}}">{{row.entity.entityName}}</a>' + '</div>'
    }, {
        name: "entityCode",
        width: "15%"
    }, {
        name: "codeType"
    }, {
        name: "Entity Type",
        field: "entityType.entityTypeName"
    }, {
        name: "reportingId"
    }, {
        name: "Country",
        field: "country.countryName"
    }, {
        name: "startDate",
        field: "reportTypeObligationTypes.startDate"
    }, {
        name: "endDate",
        field: "reportTypeObligationTypes.endDate"
    }, {
        name: "consolidationScopeCode",
        field: "reportTypeObligationTypes.consolidationScopeCode"
    }, {
        name: "frequencyLabel",
        field: "reportTypeObligationTypes.frequencyLabel"
    }, {
        name: "Delete",
        cellTemplate: '<div style="margin-left: 5px;">' + '  <a href="#delete/{{row.entity.entityId}}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn btn-danger"> Delete</a>' + '</div>',
        enableFiltering: false,
        enableSorting: false
    }];

})
```

HTML Page - Angular UI grid

```
<div ng-app="xxxApp" ng-controller="reportListController">

<p class="heading">Entities with Reporting Obligation</p>

<!-- Entities list data table using - 'ui-grid' module  -->
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="myGrid" ui-grid-pagination
    ui-grid-selection ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-move-columns
    ui-grid-cellNav ui-grid-exporter></div>
```

Comment: can you use a binding that points to a function, and have a function that returns an array based on the JSON you have?

Comment: Put html code too please!

Comment: Is there an error message? Typically with angular we display array data in html using ng-repeat.

Comment: I have added my html code too.Nick, I dont have any error message.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, assign `$scope.reportTypeObligationTypes = [{JSON}];`
Your tag or directive ex:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in reportTypeObligationTypes">
  <div>{{item.startDate}}</div>
  <div>{{item.endDate}}</div>
</div>
```

'item' will represent each JSON object in the array and you can use `item.(property)`. To reference each object property.

**EDIT:TRY:**

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  data: $scope.myData,
  columnDefs: [
    { name: 'field1', displayName: 'pretty display name' },
    { name: 'field2', visible: false }
 ]
};
```

Comment: This should work from what SGN has posted, sounds like he is new to angular.

Comment: Hi Shinobi, I use Angular UI grid in my html.

Comment: The ui-grid APi is saying that you should set the data collections to `$scope.data = reportTypeObligationTypes`first and then set `$scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.data` **Look at the edit above**